# Best way to utilize a serializer in Ember.js to support a different payload key?

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, payload

When running the following line of code:

```
this.get('store').query('domain-message', 
{
    domainId: user.defaultDomain.id
});

>>/api/domain-messages?domainId=1
```

this error is returned:

> The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record. Please wrap your response in an array or use `store.queryRecord` to query for a single record. Error: Assertion Failed: The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record. Please wrap your response in an array or use `store.queryRecord` to query for a single record.

I have a model in **app/pods/domain-message/model.js** that looks like so:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    campaignId: attr('number'),
    orgId: attr('number'),
    orgName: attr('string'),
    userId: attr('number'),
    memberId: attr('number'),
    messageSubject: attr('string'),
    messageBody: attr('string'),
    attachmentLink: attr('string'),
    //sentTimestamp: attr('date'),
    //receivedTimestamp: attr('date'),
    //archivedTimestamp: attr('date'),
    messageSeen: attr('boolean'),
    messageRead: attr('boolean'),
    parentMessageId: attr('number'),
    actionCount: attr('number'),
    completedActionCount: attr('number'),
    //actionStatusUpdatedTimestamp: attr('date'),
});
```

When inspecting the network for this query, the payload data is as follows:

```
{"messages":[{"id":1,"campaignId":1,"orgId":1,"orgName":"TestOrg","userId":120,"memberId":"12345","messageSubject":"Test Message","messageBody":"test test test","attachmentLink":"https://google.com","sentTimestamp":null,"receivedTimestamp":"2019-08-07T17:01:39Z","archivedTimestamp":null,"messageSeen":false,"messageRead":false,"parentMessageId":0,"actionCount":0,"completedActionCount":0,"actionStatusUpdatedTimestamp":"2019-08-07T17:01:39Z"},{"id":2,"campaignId":1,"orgId":1,"orgName":"TestOrg2","userId":120,"memberId":"12349","messageSubject":"Hello","messageBody":"How are you?","attachmentLink":"https://google.com","sentTimestamp":null,"receivedTimestamp":"2019-08-07T17:07:39Z","archivedTimestamp":null,"messageSeen":false,"messageRead":false,"parentMessageId":0,"actionCount":0,"completedActionCount":0,"actionStatusUpdatedTimestamp":"2019-08-07T17:07:39Z"}],"meta":{"count":2,"total":2,"offset":null,"limit":null}}
```

Notice how the payloadKey is "members", this may be causing the issue since it may have to be the same as the models name. Is there anyway to modify this payloadKey and change it so that the model above supports it?

I am not using a serializer, but I do know that it may be required to do so to make this work. Can anyone suggest the best route to suppress this error? When generating a serializer, it will be located in **app/pods/domain-message/serializer.js**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom serializer has solved this issue. Both RESTSerializer and JSONSerializer works in this situation.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    normalizeQueryResponse(store, ModelClass, payload, id, requestName) {
        return this._super(store, ModelClass, payload.messages, id, requestName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not providing an Serializer explicitly, Ember Data will fall back to the default one, which is [`JSONAPISerializer`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/JSONAPISerializer). `JSONAPISerializer` expects your API to be complaint with [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/), which isn't the case for the payload included in your question. Therefore you must provide a serializer that can handle your API responses. It shouldn't be that much work, if you extend [`RESTSerializer`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/RESTSerializer). Please have a look in the [Customizing Serializers chapter of Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/) for an introduction on that topic.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! I've taken into account a custom serializer and made it work by normalizing the response using normalizeQueryResponse and targeting the "messages" payload key.